# I want to delete/remove an attribute in a node in xml if it matches to my key=value using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have tried using `$node.RemoveAttribute($name)`.

Consider following:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="User" />
    <section name="Admin" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

I would want to delete `name="User"` and not `name="Admin"`

If I use following, both attributes are being removed.

```
 [xml]$Xml=Get-Content Web.config
    $path=".//configuration/configSections/section"
    $element="name"
    $node = $xml.SelectNodes($path)
    $node.RemoveAttribute($element)
```

I'm new to Powershell.

Comment: Do you want the whole node `<section name="User" />`, or just the attribute `Name`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content "filepath")
$xml.configuration.configsections.section | foreach {
  if ($_.name -eq "user") {
    $_.removeattribute("name")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick input. But no luck.

Comment: How? I have tested this and this works! Please test again.

Comment: What if $xml.configuration.configsections.section is dynamicand there are multiple nodes with this attribute?

Comment: Thank you Wasif. It worked. I just replaced $_.name with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the Attribute "name" and leave the node in place, but empty, you can follow Wasif's answer, here as one-liner:

```
$xml.configuration.configsections.section | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "user" } | ForEach-Object { $_.RemoveAttribute("name") }
```

Result:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <configSections>
>     <section />
>     <section name="Admin" />
>   </configSections>
> </configuration>
> ```

If what you want is to remove the node that has an attribute "name" with value "User", you can do this instead:

```
$xml.configuration.configsections.section | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "user" } | ForEach-Object { $null = $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
```

Result:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <configSections>
>     <section name="Admin" />
>   </configSections>
> </configuration>
> ```

---

As per your comment, if there are more than one nodes with attribute 'name="User"' and you want to only remove the first occurrence, do:

```
$firstNode = $xml.configuration.configsections.section | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "user" } | Select-Object -First 1 
$null = $firstNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild($firstNode)
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks Theo,What if $xml.configuration.configsections.section is dynamicand there are multiple nodes with this attribute?

Comment: @KSD I have edited my answer to show how to remove only the first occurrence if more nodes exist with the same property. Please, if you want to comment so I get notified, write `@theoneyouwishtoaddress`.